# How to run a method on RadioButton click more than once for the same RadioButton in Android?

Tags: android, radio-button

I am using a `switch` to control actions on clicking a `RadioButtion`. However, when I click a particular `RadioButton`, the related code only runs once. I cannot select the same `RadioButton` again. How do I allow the same button to be pressed more than once and still execute the related code each time?

Comment: You should explain this little bit more....

Comment: `onClick()` fires on every click, so add your code.

Comment: Why would you want to click a radiobutton multiple times?

Comment: If one of the Answers below answers your question, please be sure to select it as 'correct' so that others may better find a solution to similar issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What i understood is that you want a RadioButton to be clicked multiple times

You are probably using **setOnCheckedChangeListener**

You should try **setOnClickListener** instead, like a button in android

Something like this should work:

```
 RadioButton radio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);

 radio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "THIS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
  });
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You should consider unchecking the RadioButton so it can be re-selected. You can do that by trying `((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioButton)).setChecked(false)`, or simply creating another invisible RadioButton and using `setChecked(true)` on that new button.

You can also try the `clearCheck()` in `RadioGroup`:

```
RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.name);
group.clearCheck();
```

Comment: Yes, this seems like what OP is trying to do.